# What is this number associated with my typeid?

Tags: c++, inheritance, typeid

Program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
        public:virtual void func(){}
};

class Derived1 : public Base {};

int main()
{
        Derived1 d;
        cout<<typeid(d).name()<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
8Derived1
```

What is this number **8**?

Compiler:  g++-4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04

Comment: I don't think the answers, the question `8` stands for the number of characters in the name.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Well, that may be one implementation (to return its size + name), but it is not guaranteed by the c++ specification: "Returns an implementation defined null-terminated character string containing the name of the type. No guarantees are given (...)"

Comment: @DavidNogueira the OP specifically asking about gcc, as noted in the question

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Indeed, further detailed regarding g++-4.8.4-2 implementation I cannot offer.

Answer (score 2):

It is implementation defined, and has no inherent meaning. Check [std::typeinfo::name() reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) :

> Returns an implementation defined null-terminated character string containing the name of the type. No guarantees are given, in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program.

Comment: Wonder what it is used for? Seems pretty useless with that description.

Comment: @StillLearning I would point that it could be used by some platform-locked applications/libraries with knowledge of its implementation, but that this function should probably not be used by a end-user. Just my 2 cents.